# how to convert ASCII to Hexadecimal in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

To start with I am not really sure what ASCII is (I have googled it but no luck in understanding), anyway I am solving an exercise for learners and came across this problem and the answer is the following code.

I found few statements and concepts hard to understand in this code which are the following:

1. what is the purpose of 2 initializations `var n = 0, l = str.length` for the For loop?
2. what is `charCodeAt(n)`

   I learned it's unicode, but what does this to this function and how is n related to charCodeAt and how both are related to hexadecimal to ASCII conversion?
3. Why does `.toString()` have the value of 16 assigned to it.

   It seems to me like it has to with hex hence 16, but how is it related to converting hexadecimal to ASCII?

.

```
function ascii_to_hexa(str)  
{  
  var arr1 = [];  
  for (var n = 0, l = str.length; n < l; n ++)   
  {  
    var hex = Number(str.charCodeAt(n)).toString(16);  
    arr1.push(hex);  
  }  
  return arr1.join('');  
}
```

Comment: ascii is just a list of numeric values that refer to the certain characters in your computer.  "A" for instance has a value of 65 (or 41 in hexadecimal).  "a" on the other hand has a value of 97, the escape character is 27, enter key gives you 13 and so on.  If you look up "ascii chart" you'll find full tables of what characters have what values.

Answer (score 1):

```
var n = 0, l = str.length; n < l; n ++
```

do the loop while `n` is less than string length - basically, loop through each character in the string. When you get to the end of the string, stop looping.

`n` is the character in the string where the loop is at (1, 2, 3, ...) and therefore the character to be converted.

16 is the number base to use when calculating the character value. It is called the radix. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString

Answer (score 0):

1. What is the purpose of 2 inizialtions(var n = 0, l = str.length) for the For loop?

   The variable `l` is just storing the value of `str.length`. You could write `for (var n = 0; n < str.length; n ++)` instead and it would also be valid.
2. What is charCodeAt(n), I learned it's unicode, but what does this to this function and how is n related to charCodeAt and how both are related to hexadecimal to ASCII conversio?

   `charCodeAt` you can read for yourself, it's well described in the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt
3. Why .toString() has the value of 16 assigned to it, it seems to me like it has to with hexa hence 16, but how is it related to converting hexadecimal to ASCII?

   `toString()` has a radix parameter, specifying the base to use. This tells it to use base 16.